# Java preferences file in gibberish directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, preferences

I designated my prefs in a large java application (in Intellij) as

```
private final Preferences root = Preferences.userRoot();
private final Preferences prefs = root.node("/org/gs_users/gs_mv");
```

The designation corresponds to the java package name.

After I ran the application, and looked for the prefs.xml file, I found:
[shows in ~/home/.java as:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGfXs.jpg)

I tried different ways of specifying preference root and node. But every time I ran the application, a new gibberish directory appeared with a different combination of letters and symbols, even when I didn't change anything. Although the application runs otherwise perfectly, I can't release it like this.

Comment: *"the application runs otherwise perfectly"* - So what's the problem?  Why does the contents of the `prefs.xml` make any difference, so long as it's running?  The preferences API is intended to be a "black hole" API, the actual storage and management mechanisms are suppose to be independent of the application and platform (for example, on Windows it gets stored in the registery)

Comment: confirmed on my system, I get the same so called "gibberish" directories - but the names are not changed from run to run, and the saved value is retrieved successfully: some characters are not accepted in file/directory names - these must be somehow escaped - "org" for example is just using alphabetical letters and is not changed, the other names are using `_` which forces the names to be encoded - try `root.node("/org/gsusers/gsmv")`

Comment: Thank you, user16320675. You hit the nail on the head! It was the darned underline (_). By simply eliminating this one character from the package designation my problem was solved., and everything is working, as it should.

Answer (score 0):

May be I can be wrong, but apparently you are trying to use Preferences class for the conservation of the directory (for example, a user can choose a directory for an export/import of files and then the chosen dicrectory will be used as a default one). Did you try to create the userRoot only without creating the prefs one?

```
    private final Preferences user = Preferences.userRoot();
    
    String defaultString = "defaultString";
    String preferenceDirectory = this.user.get(defaultStr, null);
    if(preferenceDirectory != null){
        File defaultInitialDirectory = new File(preferenceDirectory);
        fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(defaultInitialDirectory);
    }
```

Like this, the application will remember the directory or any other preference you need. I also agree with @MadProgrammer that the prefs.xml file is techincal and is for system use only.